# jQuery show item when jquery generated css is finished loading

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

Is there a way to hide an object until my script is done loading? Using ajaxcomplete() or ajaxSuccess() didn't work. Below an example script.

there is an image with the id: imagefocus, every time i change the image via ajax, you see for a split second the original image size.

```
$("#imageFocus").bind("load", function(){
    var width = $(this).width();
    var height = $(this).height();

   if(height > 443) {
        var scaleRatio  = height / 443,
            width       = Math.round(width / scaleRatio),
            mLeft       = Math.round((590 - width) / 2);
        $(this).css({
            height:     "443px",
            width:      width+"px"
        });
        $(this).parent().css({
                marginTop:  "0px",
                marginLeft: mLeft+"px"
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hide the image through css and then show it on it's `load` event. Also before you make ajax call hide the image, the below code will take care of showing it once the image is loaded.

Css

```
#imageFocus{
    display:none;
}
```

JS

```
$("#imageFocus").bind("load", function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var width = $this.width();
    var height = $this.height();

   if(height > 443) {
        var scaleRatio  = height / 443,
            width       = Math.round(width / scaleRatio),
            mLeft       = Math.round((590 - width) / 2);

        $this
        .css({
            height:     "443px",
            width:      width+"px"
        })
        .show() //<---------Show the image
        .parent()
        .css({
                marginTop:  "0px",
                marginLeft: mLeft+"px"
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. So simple yet so effective. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, start with:

```
$("#imageFocus").hide()
```

and end with (in your load function)

```
$("#imageFocus").show()
```

Comment: i tried this, didn't work. #imagefocus is a image, every time the image changes via ajax, you still see for a split second the original image size.

Comment: Before hiding, use: $("#imageFocus").attr('src','')

Answer (score 0):

That happens because the load finishes and auto-inserts your image. You cannot achieve the behavior you want in the actualcallback. Instead create a function, that hides the image and after that loads the new one. Then in the callback, make it visible again